# Async function runs continuously

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm using the following code to fetch data from two different sources in react using hooks.

```
const [ permissionTree, setPermissionTree ] = useState([]);
const [ availablePermissionsInRole, setAvailablePermissionsInRole ] = useState<Permission[]>([]);

const getAllPermissions = (): void => {
    getPermissionList()
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200 && response.data && response.data instanceof Array) {
                const permissionStringArray = response.data;
                let permissionTree: Permission[] = [];

                permissionTree = permissionStringArray.reduce((arr, path) => addPath(
                    path, path.resourcePath.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split('/'), arr,
                ), []);

                setPermissionTree(permissionTree);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //Handle Permission Retrieval Properly
        })
}

/**
 * Retrieve permissions for a given role if in Role edit mode.
 */
useEffect(() => {
    if (isEdit && roleObject) {
        getPermissionsForRole(roleObject.id)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200 && response.data instanceof Array) {
                    const permissionsArray: Permission[] = [];
                    response.data.forEach(permission => {
                        permissionsArray.push({
                            id: permission,
                            isChecked: false,
                            fullPath: permission
                        })
                    })
                    setAvailablePermissionsInRole(permissionsArray);
                    getAllPermissions();
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //Handle Role Retrieval Properly
            })
    } else {
        getAllPermissions();
    }
}, [])
```

The first async call `getPermissionsForRole` returns a string array and the second `getAllPermissions` returns an array of objects which I then parse on to a util method to create a different array of objects.

With an empty array as the second argument in `useEffect` the continuous async call is stopped but when I check `availablePermissionsInRole` inside the `getAllPermissions` method, it's empty. When I pass `availablePermissionsInRole` as the second argument the continuous loop occurs.

What am I doing wrong in this code. Please guide me since I'm new to react hooks.

Comment: `useEffect` (without a dependencies array) does something after every render, but calling `setPermissionTree` will trigger a re-render.

Comment: Are you passing `availablePermissionsInRole` ***as the second parameter*** or ***in*** the dependency array, which is the second parameter?

Comment: As I have mentioned when I pass the `availablePermissionsInRole` as the second argument, the infinite loop happens.

Comment: So what happens if you pass `[availablePermissionsInRole]` as the second parameter?

Comment: The `getAllPermissions` method runs in an infinite loop.

Comment: It appears the effect hook *sets* that value, so if you add that value to the dependency array it will cause infinite loop without some further guard check in the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the infinite loop of the `useEffect` and since I pass the `availablePermissionsInRole` as the second argument, react look only at the array reference and treats it as a new array hence the infinite loop. As a fix for this I first passed the following as the argument.

```
availablePermissionsInRole.length
```

which will stay the same unless the backend sends a new array element. Then again the strings inside the array could change without the length being changed so I used the following as the arguement which fixes my issue.

```
availablePermissionsInRole.toString()
```

Which then changes if a new string is also retrieved.

Thank you all for the help but do point out if there is any errors in the approach I have used.

Comment: Wouldn't `roleObject.id` need to be a dependency as well?

Comment: Since the state I'm keeping is the `availablePermissionsInRole` I think it should be the dependency the function depends on.

Comment: You *can* depend on more than one dependency.

Comment: @ImeshChandrasiri You've said *twice* now that you "pass the `availablePermissionsInRole` *as* the second argument" but haven't exactly clarified if you actually pass it *as the second argument* or if you pass *in the dependency array* as *part* of the second argument. Can you be explicit now and show us how you're passing it to the effect? And OFC using `availablePermissionsInRole` *in* the dependency array cause infinite loop, the effect updates *that* state value.